# Java 2D game. What to do instead of calling addnotify?

Tags: java, graphics2d, game-loop

I'm mkaing a 2D game in java.

so far my code is this:

Game.java:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame("Snake! - By Casida");
    gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gameWindow.add(new GamePanel());
    gameWindow.pack();
    gameWindow.setResizable(false);
    gameWindow.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

GamePanel.java, this is where i override addNotify().

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {

//Dimensions
public static final int WIDTH = 384;
public static final int HEIGHT = 384;
public static final int SCALE = 2;

//Game loop
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private int FPS = 60;
private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

//Image
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g;

public GamePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();

    if(thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}

private void init() {
    running = true;
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    init();

    long start;
    long elapsed;
    long wait;

    while(running) {

        start = System.nanoTime();

        update();
        draw();
        drawToScreen();

        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

        if(wait < 0)
            wait = 5;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void update() {

}

public void draw() {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public void drawToScreen() {
    Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
    g2.dispose();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I've seen that it is discouraged to override the addNotify method, but what do i need to do, to get the same result, without overriding it?

Comment: Don't use KeyListener, use key bindings, don't use getGraphics, override paintComponent, don't dispose of a Graphics context you did not "create" yourself. Move the main thread out to its own class, pass a reference of the panel to it. Create this thread once you have created the rest of the UI. Swing components are foible buffered by default, so unless you have an absolute reason to do so, you don't need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Most of what your saying makes sense to me. What do mean with moving the main thread out to it's own class? i tried to make a game loop by overriding paintComponent, But i fail to see how i can put it in a loop.

Comment: Don't put the loop in paintComponent, paintComponent should just paint the current state of the game. Place the "game loop" in its own class, provide it with a reference to the "game model" and some means to instruct the UI to update it self (the model could be used to trigger an event, or you could call repaint directly). This helps decouple your code and makes it reusable in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your "game loop" into its own class, possibly implementing `Runnable`. Use some kind of model that is shared between the panel and the "game loop". The "game loop" should update the state of the model and the panel should paint it.

If needed, you might consider using an interface which would allow the "game loop" to notify the UI that it should update itself

Once you've created the UI, you would construct the "game loop" class and start it

- Don't use `KeyListener`, use [Key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
- Don't use `getGraphics`, override `paintComponent` and perform your custom painting there. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details. Swing uses a passive rendering engine, meaning updates could occur at any time, most without you doing anything. Anything painting using `getGraphics` will be paintings over, this could cause unexpected and difficult to replicate flickering
- Don't dispose of a `Graphics` context you did not "create", this could prevent future updates from occurring
- Swing components are double buffered by default, so unless you have a pressing need to do so, you don't need to reinvent the wheel